# How can I change "Created By" in Google Calendar using google calendar api?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I've given the creator object with name and email id, but still it gets saved in the google calendar with my gmail ID only.

```
    {
      "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-07-20T20:30:00.392227",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
      },
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-07-20T20:00:00.392227",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
      },
      "summary": "Birthday Party",
      "creator": {
        "displayName": "Lara",
        "email": "lara@gmail.com"
        "self": true
      }
    }
```

What should I do to change the Creator or "Created By" under events in Google Calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think these properties (`creator`, `creator.displayName`, `creator.email`, `creator.id`, `creator.self`) are editable as they are marked as Read-only property in [Events resources](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events). You may only use them as is.